# htaccess: How to redirect index.php?search= to the base url

Tags: url-rewriting

how can i redirect index.php?search= to the base url? I tried it with this code:

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/index.php?search=(.*) http://www.yoursite.com/
```

but then the page loops the code if i enter the site domain..

Comment: You want to redirect or rewrite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) does only work on the [URL path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax) and not the query:

> mod_alias is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks. For more complicated tasks such as manipulating the query string, use the tools provided by mod_rewrite.

So try [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(.*)
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ /? [L,R=301]
```

Or more general:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&+)*search=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ /? [L,R=301]
```

And if you want to use this rule the .htaccess file in your root directory, remove the leading slash from the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/index.php?search=(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/
```